# Guess the "special number" of an unfair die given the first $N$ tosses

Tags: probability, estimation

The following problem is something I have come up with recently, and have been trying to solve, but to no avail. I wonder whether the solution is relatively easy, or pretty complicated:

---

Suppose we have an unfair die, such that the probability to get the number $s\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is $p$, where $p>1/6$ and $s$ is deterministic (but unknown). We call $s$ the *special* number. Suppose that the probability to get an element of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\setminus\{s\}$ (i.e., not a special number) is $(1-p)/5$. We denote $X_n$ to be the result of the $n$-th toss. Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$, and suppose we know the results of first $N$ tosses: $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{N}$.

Given the first $N$ results, we want to guess (estimate) the special number $s$. We do this with a *majority vote*: We pick the *mode* of the sequence $X_n$. In other words:

$$\hat{s}=\underset{k\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}}{\mathrm{argmax}}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{N}1_{\{X_i=k\}}\right\}$$

Where $1_{\{A\}}$ is the indicator function of the event $A$. What is the probability  that $\hat{s}\neq s$ in terms of $N$ and $p$?

- You can assume that there isn't a tie in the majority vote (meaning, $\hat{s}$ is defined well).

---

The only thing that I am certain of is:

$$\mathbb{P}\{\hat{s}\neq s\}=1-\mathbb{P}\{\hat{s}=s\}=1-\frac 16\sum_{k=1}^{6}\mathbb{P}\{\hat{s}=k|s=k\}=1-\mathbb{P}\{\hat{s}=6|s=6\}$$

This is due to symmetry.

Comment: Are you sure $\hat{s}$ is well defined? You can have an outcome of $N$ rolls in which every number from $1$ to $6$ is the mode.

Comment: @MatthewPilling The OP said to assume there is no tie.  Perhaps the question should be rephrased as, "Given that there is a single mode, what is the probability that is the special number?"

Comment: I didn't catch that. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: I suspect this will be difficult (especially since ties can happen), and you may find simulation is faster for any particular case.

Comment: My attempt with $10^5$ simulations of $100$ rolls with $p=0.2$, spotted the special value about $67\%$ of the time, another value about $25\%$ of the time, plus ties including the special value in about $6\%$ of cases and ties not including the special value in about $2\%$ of cases.

Comment: [This paper] (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2334165) seems like it might be relevant.  I haven't read it it; it's just the most promising thing I found in a quick Google search.